# Can one capture the reallocations of std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, realloc

I know that push_back() on an std::vector can cause reallocation and therefore invalidate iterators in the pointer. Is there a way of installing a hook on reallocations (which presumably happen very seldom) so that I can adjust iterators appropriately?

Ideally something like this:

```
class hook; // forward
std::vectorwithhook<T,hook> v;
auto pointer = v.end();

template<> class hook<T> {
  void operator()(T *old, T *new) { pointer += new-old; }
}
```

and then I can push_back() on v and play with pointer with no fear.

Comment: `std::vector` takes `Allocator` at last template parameter. Don't know if you have enough info from there though.

Comment: The "real world solution" here is probably to reserve enough space beforehand, fill the vector strictly before starting to iterate it, or just treat every `push_back` as a potential reallocation that invalidates all iterators.

Comment: Every standard container uses an allocator to allocate, reallocate, and deallocate memory.  Therefore creating an allocator that tracks all operations would work.   Creating allocators is non-trivial, but the standard allows it, and there are tutorials around on how to do it.   Recognising that an arbitrary iterator (or pointer) was obtained before a reallocation would be more difficult though.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in the allocator to "fix" up the iterators; since (in general) the allocator isn't involved in creating iterators.

Comment: Inserting and erasing elements in the vector also invalidates iterators, even with no reallocation involved.

Comment: @MarshallClow The allocator would only need to fire callbacks when, say, reallocating, not necessarily be involved with touching iterators directly.

Comment: why not just use reserve(). It will reallocate itself when used push_back() after reserve limit.!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest way to do this would be to have your vectorwithhook::push_back return the new end() and use it like:

pointer = v.push_back(new_item);

NOTE: you would have to do this for all members that change content of the vector (e.g. emplace_back, pop_back, insert etc...)

Alternatively, it should also be possible by creating your own allocator type, which will take a reference to iterator and the container in constructor and update it every time allocator::allocate(...) or allocator::dellocate(...) is called. NOTE that this goes against the principals of STL that was designed to have iterators, containers, allocators separate from one another...

P.S. none of this sounds like a good idea tbh, I would think about reworking the code to avoid keeping the end() iterator instead of doing any of this.

Comment: Thanks for all the insights! It's a bit disappointing to me that my code has to use lots of integer-indices rather than pointers in std::vectors. STL is smart enough to re-validate end() after reallocations, why can't it do it for other classes?
None of this is life-threatening, but I would be happy to have the better performance and simpler code.

Comment: hmm, not sure what you mean by "STL is smart enough to re-validate end() after reallocations, why can't it do it for other classes?" ? end() of all STL containers always returns one-past-end element in the container, irrelevant of how many insert/remove(s) you perform. the problem in your case is that you are keeping an iterator as "auto pointer = v.end()" and then changing the "v". If you can refactor the code to just call v.end() whenever the "past-the-end" element is needed you wouldn't have to worry about reallocations at all. also end() is const-time so performance shouldn't be a problem.